# ListView's equivalent to Column's mainAxisSize in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to clean up my widget tree and to replicate a `ListView`, I use `Padding>SingleChildScrollView>Column` with a `MainAxisSize.min` property. I would like to use `ListView` instead but I run into an issue with buttons. The buttons always use the max width (the entire screen width) when I want to specify a size (ex. 1/3 of the screen size). I have to use those three widgets in order to be able to size a button properly unless there's a widget that I don't know of that would help me.

Here's an example with the `ListView` widget:

[image: button with listview]

And an example without a `ListView` widget:

[image: button without listview]

Comment: Wrap your Listview with Container and give height and width to your Container Using MediaQuery

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your `button` with a `Center()` widget